# How to get Google Now to give me timely commute advice?

Tags: google-now

The last few days I've travelled to work, there's been a huge amount of traffic, causing major delays and lengthening my 30 minute commute to at least 45 minutes. I have Google Now on my phone, and without fail, *every day*, it will tell me there's heavy traffic on my route to work - about five minutes *before* I arrive at work. I usually leave pretty early - about 7.15am - but it's the same time every day.

So is there a way to get Google Now to give me these notifications earlier - i.e. before I leave the house?